# Getting text from a textField in JavaFX

Tags: button, javafx, text, field

I've got a program that I have to make into a JavaFX program, and I can't get my input data off of my textfields. I've spent a good 3 hours looking for a reason, and I can't seem to get any answer. Here's my controller

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class WeatherController {
    @FXML
    protected TextField stateTextField;
    @FXML
    protected TextField cityField;
    @FXML
    protected Button submitButton;

    @FXML
    protected void init(){
        System.out.println("Program running!");

    }
    @FXML
    private void handleSubmitButton(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println(stateTextField.getText());
    }

}
```

And here's the stack Trace I get. I'm not quite sure, but it seems to be erroring in the handle action method.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=63504:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\JohnK\IdeaProjects\weatherfxx\target\classes;C:\Users\JohnK\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.8.3\jsoup-1.8.3.jar" Main
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at WeatherController.handleSubmitButton(WeatherController.java:24)
    ... 58 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

FXML file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="WeatherController">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <Label id="titleLabel" contentDisplay="TOP" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="631.0" text="Weather Search" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
            <font>
                <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <TextField id="cityTextField" onAction="#handleSubmitButton" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Label text="Enter a state:" textAlignment="RIGHT" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            <font>
                <Font size="14.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <Label text="Enter a city:" textAlignment="RIGHT" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
            <font>
                <Font size="14.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
            <image>
                <Image url="@logo_130x80.png" />
            </image></ImageView>
        <TextField id="stateTextField" onAction="#handleSubmitButton" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Button id="submitButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSubmitButton" text="Submit All" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: You should include the FXML file to get a complete answer. But as most of JavaFX beginner, it seems you forget to set `fx:id="stateTextField"` in your corresponding `TextField`.

Comment: How have you wired it to your fxml? What event is triggering that handler? The null pointer exception is obvious the textfield is null

Comment: Post the FXML file in the question.

Comment: @James_D I added the fxml.

Comment: @JohnKeith can you confirm that Pagbo's answer was correct?

Comment: @SirajK it didn't do anything, but I spoke with my professor and he mentioned something about JavaFX not playing along with very nicely with Maven projects